# Unit Test: Testing if a dataframe contains specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, unit-testing

I'm creating a unit test for some functions, in one of the tests, I would like test whether the new columns were created or not. Therefore I would like to test that the names of certain columns are in the output dataframe `df_output` from one of the functions. I have a list containing the names of the expected newly created columns `List_Match`. How can I do that as a unit test ?

```
A simplified example of my data: 
d = {'ID_EMPLOYEE': [12, 35, 56, 46], 'Number':[0,1,2,30], 'Location_EMPLOYEE':["US","US","Austria","France"], 'Salary':[100,200,100,160]}
df_output=pd.DataFrame(d)

List_Match=["Location_EMPLOYEE","ID_EMPLOYEE"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
assert all([col in df_output.columns for col in List_Match])
```

Alternative Solution without loop:

```
assert len(set(List_Match)&set(df_output.columns))==len(set(List_Match))
```

Explanation:

1. Check each expected column in output
2. Perform all to verify everything is present
3. use assert to test your code

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice way to test for a list of columns, and give information about which are missing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
required_cols = ['one', 'two', 'four', 'five']
missing_cols = set(required_cols) - set(df.columns)
assert not missing_cols, f"Columns missing: {', '.join(missing_cols)}"
```

Note that this only tests that `required_cols` are present. It doesn't check whether there are any extra columns or not.